# Splitting shapefile into separate shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, multipart, split-by-attribute

I have a multipart shapefile, which I would like to split into many individual shapefiles (by FID for example).

Is there some way to do this in ArcGIS 10.x without using python?